# C++ class this-> error

Tags: c++, oop, class

```
class Bot{
private:
       char *serveradr;
public:
       char *get_serveradr(); 
       char set_serveradr(char *server);
       void servcon();                
       };

char Bot::set_serveradr(char *server)
 {
 serveradr = server;
 }

 char *Bot::get_serveradr()
 {
 return serveradr;


 void servcon()
 {
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr           = inet_addr(this.get_serveradr());

  }
```

> invalid use of `this' in non-member function

Sorry for such a question but I've searched and know this is how it should be done but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the name of the member function defintion:

```
void Bot::servcon()
{
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(this->get_serveradr()); // Note use of ->

}
```

Otherwise, it is treated as a free standing function which do not have a `this` pointer.

As this is C++, use a `std::string` instead of a `char*`. The argument passed to the `Bot::set_serveradr()` method must outlive `Bot` which is error prone (and who is responsible for `delete[]`ing it?). You can access a `char*` using `std::string::c_str()` method.

Comment: thanks hmjd for the fast reply but  this->, this:: and this. all result in the same error.

Comment: There is a missing `}` for `get_serveradr()`. Compiled fine when I made that change (plus returning a value from `set_serveradr()`) with VS2010 and http://ideone.com/NMxaa

Comment: Hi i must have edited it out, you and mathematician1975 where both right thanks for your fast reply :). Thanks for the advice ill look into std::string

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
    void servcon()
    {
       ... 
    }
```

with

```
    void Bot::servcon()
    {
       ... 
    }
```

just like you have done with the other member function definitions

Comment: Iv been staring at the code for over an hour and i missed then. Thanks!

Comment: You also need to use this-> rather than this. just like the other answer here states or you will still get an error.